# Unable to Start Spark Driver in a Docker Container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a docker container which contains a java application which starts a spark driver. It connects to a spark cluster and submits a structured streaming application.

When I run the docker in host mode with the `--network host` argument or with the `--hostname 10.X.X.X` argument things work perfectly. However, as I am using elastic beanstalk to run the application, I cannot modify the docker command used to start the container. Additionally, there is no option to change the networking mode or hostname with elastic beanstalk.

When I run the docker without either of those arguments, the docker fails to start with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (starting from 37878)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:558) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1283) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:989) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:254) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:364) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138) ~[news-ml-IT-148-2.jar:IT-148-2]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
```

I have tried the following:

1. Updating /etc/hosts
2. Updating /etc/hostname
3. Setting spark.driver.host
4. Setting spark.driver.port
5. Setting the $HOSTNAME environment variable
6. Setting the $SPARK_LOCAL_IP environment variable
7. Setting the $SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS environment variable
8. Pretty much every combination of the above.

Unfortunately I cannot set the hostname with the `hostname` command as that requires the SYS_ADMIN capability (which the docker container is run without). I cannot add that capability because I cannot change the command used to run the docker container (nor would I want to even if I could). I realize that it is a bit silly to run a spark driver in an elastic beanstalk. However, I'd like to maintain this in order to minimize the changes that need to be made (and get this out as soon as possible) - what can I do to get this working?

Comment: have you tried to set port explicitly to spark-submit using `spark.driver.port`?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes - I've updated the question to include that.